# How do I send post request with json body where the body only contains a string not a key value pair?

Tags: javascript, json, string, post, key-value

Some developer who does not know proper json format is key value pair made the json body just a string so it looks like this: 
{
   "dog"
}

rather than 
{
   "dog": "dog"
}

I need to send the request from a javascript file and the body must be JSON. I have tried sending raw JSON with Ajax, fetch, Axios, and xmlHttp but they are all formatting it into key value pair. How should I send this request?

Comment: If the body must be JSON, then that's that - the `{ "dog" }` you're given is just not proper JSON. Best to just fix it wherever that malformed string originates.

Comment: if you need something without a key you can send something like that: `["dog"]`

Comment: Is `{ "dog" }` a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
  body: '{ "dog" }'
})
```

This will send the string `{ "dog" }` in the body, if that is what the endpoint you are trying to use expects. Just... don't call it JSON. It's as much a JSON as pudding is a hammer.